# Highcharts 3D - Gridlines not adjusting according to alpha beta angle in options3D in line chart and bar chart

Tags: angular, highcharts

I plot the 3D bar char, its frame color and bars are plotted on the alpha and beta angle set in the chart but the grid lines have an altogether different alignment unlike the plotted bars. The labels at xAxis and yAxis are also along the gridlines and on different angles.

How can i adjust the grid lines to move according to alpha and beta values in options3D?

*Can't figure out why the same chart works fine in JSFiddle but not in my app.

```
const chart = new Chart(<any>{
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 35,
      beta: 0,
      // axisLabelPosition: 'auto',
      //  fitToPlot : true,
    },
},
title: {
    text: '3D chart with null values'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Notice the difference between a 0 value and a null point'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: Highcharts.getOptions().lang.shortMonths,
     title: {
      text: 'OKKKK',
     },
    labels: {
       skew3d: true,
        style: {
            fontSize: '16px'
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: null
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Sales',
    data: [2, 3, null, 4, 0, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3]
}]
```

[image]

[image]

***highcharts-3d*** version 0.1.7

***highcharts*** version 6.2.0

Comment: Could you prepare a simplified online demo of your app? Are you using the official `highcharts-angular` wrapper?

Comment: I have now found a way to create and resolve this similar scenario in Fiddle, it requires removing "highcharts-3d.src.js" script.
https://forum.highcharts.com/post108815.html#p108815 

But i have removed the highcharts-3d.src.js script for my app and cleaned the nmp cache as well it still doesn't work in my app.

Comment: I have removed "**highcharts-3d.src.js**" from the following paths in my project **1**: node_modules\highcharts\es-modules\masters , **2**: node_modules\highcharts\js, **3**: node_modules\highcharts.